# Multiple symbols of Crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm using Crashlytics in my app to get some crash info from client, but now i am a little bit confused. For example, I have a v1.0 app on the store, and a v1.1 for testing, does uploading the v1.1 symbol overwrite the v1.0 symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

We use a unique build identifier per build, regardless of the build and version number, in order to prevent this from happening. Even if you have multiple builds with the same build and version number, the unique id let's us always map back accurately to your source code so you don't need to worry about symbols being overridden.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly!